# Ubuntu as IPv6 router

Tags: iptables, ipv6, router, static-ip, dynamic-ip

[Draw of network is here.](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/222376/custom-ipv6-network-and-security-risks)
How can I configure Ubuntu server (A) to generate dynamic IP for new end points (like B) but C server should have static IP? (Firewall: A and C server accessible via SSH only by IPv4; C server has open ports 80 and 443 on IPv6)

Comment: Do you need DHCPv6, or is [SLAAC](https://howdoesinternetwork.com/2013/slaac) enough? If so - enable ip forwarding on the Ubuntu host and set up radvd to provide routing advertisement. Note that this requires a /64. And why would by want B and C to be in front of the router? Why is C multihomed?

Comment: C server will be tested on IPv4 (private) and IPv6 (public via AAAA ns of domain, that is the reason for static IP). B should get IPv6 address automatically to test plug and play/zero configuration. DHCPv6 is needed to link mac address to static ip in this case, isn't it?

Comment: I back down from multi home solution on C if A generate dual stack network with public IPv6 addresses and private IPv4 addresses, but C should be accessible via static IPv4 from D.

Comment: You don't need DHCPv6 to get static addresses. SLAAC without privacy extensions will give you predictable IP's based on MAC address of host.

Comment: Yes, but I don't want to show mac address of raspberry to public or other mac address (like B). Just want to use fix public IPv6 for some server devices (those servers need to be accessible via IPv4 private address), and random public address for other end points.